# Duplicate items in collection by field flattening

Tags: c#, .net, linq, flatten

I have a collection: 
**[ A { 'a' => '1', 'b' => ['1', '2']}

  B { 'a' => '2', 'b' => ['1','2','3']} ]**


I'm searching for a function to 'duplicate' items in this collection to make next result:
**[ A1 { 'a' => '1', 'b' => '1'}

A2 { 'a' => '1', 'b' => '2'}

B1 { 'a' => '2', 'b' => '1'}

B2 { 'a' => '2', 'b' => '2'}

B3 { 'a' => '2', 'b' => '3'} ]**

How can i achive such result?

Comment: Can you show us the class definition of A/B (I mean the item in your collection)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very clear about your definition of class A/B. I suppose your class looks like:

```
class Data
{
    public int a;
    public int[] b;
}
```

And prepare the data like:

```
var A = new Data { a = 1, b = new[] { 1, 2, } };
var B = new Data { a = 2, b = new[] { 1, 2, 3 } };
List<Data> original = new List<Data> { A, B };
```

Using `.SelectMany` to flatten the data:

```
var result = original.SelectMany(item => 
                          item.b.Select(x => 
                             new { a = item.a, b = x }))
                     .ToList();
```

Please ignore some bad programming habits in the code(like public fields), and feel free to suggest the coding-style of the last linq query.

Comment: SelectMany definitely can do the trick. There is another overload which looks nicer for that purpose for my taste

original.SelectMany(x => x.b, (x, b) => new {a = x.a, b = b})